# Lambda expression Where clause

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, lambda

Linq convert into SQL query get value where clause `context.purposes.tolist` (id = 4000 into 4050) how it is?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        PurposeModel model = new PurposeModel();

        using (DAL.db_Hajj_UmrahEntities context = new DAL.db_Hajj_UmrahEntities())
        {
            List<DAL.Purpose> purposelist = context.Purposes.ToList();
            model.PurposeList = purposelist.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text =x.PurPose1,
                    Value=x.Id.ToString()
                });
        }

        return View(model);
}
```

Comment: question unclear. can you explain more. what do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
     context.Purposes.where(s=>s.id>=4000 && s.id<=4050).ToList();
```

Comment: thnks mysterio can you share me more lambda expression

Answer (score 0):

```
model.PurposeList = purposelist.Where(y => y.ID >= 4000 && y.ID <= 4050)
                               .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                               {
                                 Text =x.PurPose1,
                                 Value=x.Id.ToString()
                               })
                               .ToList();
```